# lodash orderBy multiple numeric fields display priority

Tags: javascript, html-table, lodash

All is going well using **orderBy** method when sorting multiple fields on an HTML table. **Score A** field will be in descending order while **Score B** field will be in an ascending order. Let's say we have this table with the following data:

```
Name     Score A     Score B
 A          3
 B                      7
 C          8
 D          1
 E                      2
```

Using **orderBy** method:

```
_.orderBy(scores, ['score_a', 'score_b'], ['desc', 'asc']);
```

The display would be:

```
Name     Score A     Score B
 E                      2
 B                      7
 C          8
 A          3
 D          1
```

However, I want to prioritize the display of a particular field and wanted **Score A** field to be displayed first instead of **Score B**. Desired display would be:

```
Name     Score A     Score B
 C          8
 A          3
 D          1
 E                      2
 B                      7
```

How to achieve this? Tried also chaining lodash methods. Is this something that should be adjusted on the display? Need your awesome inputs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Interchanging 'a' and 'b' score may solve the issue

```js
var scores = [{
    'score': 'a',
    'a': 3,
    'b': 0
  },
  {
    'score': 'b',
    'a': 0,
    'b': 7
  },
  {
    'score': 'c',
    'a': 8,
    'b': 0
  },
  {
    'score': 'd',
    'a': 1,
    'b': 0
  },
  {
    'score': 'e',
    'a': 0,
    'b': 2
  }
];

// Sort by `user` in ascending order and by `age` in descending order.
console.log(_.orderBy(scores, ['b', 'a'], ['asc', 'desc']));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! This is the first thing that I've tried but still it prioritizes the ascending order of data instead of the descending one. This is in relation on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69990431/vue-table-sorting-multiple-column-sort-in-one-header-field with Vue and lodash combined.